# Chain of Mono Void

Tags: spring-webflux

How proper work with **Mono< Void >**

For example, I have simple interface.

```
Mono<Void> void1();
Mono<Void> void2();
Mono<Void> void3();
Mono<Dto> getDto();
Mono<Dto> getDto(Param param);
```

So I want to call all **Mono< Void >** in turn (for example, they are preparing data)

And at the end of all call getDto

Is my approach correct or not?

```
    return void1()
        .then(void2()) //or thenEmpty
        .then(void3()) // or doOnNext
        .then(getDto()); // or  doOrSuccess
```

Comment: No that is correct if you wish to call them in sequence, if you wish to fire and forget (as in call the function and not care about the result) you use the `doOn` operators

Comment: Small correction. use `then` for async code and `doOn...` for sync code (so-called side-effect logic like logging or metrics)

Comment: correction to what?

Comment: All methods here are async (return ‘Mono’). ‘doOn…’ is not an option

Comment: i have no idea what you are talking about, correction to what? what are you correcting